# Get last 3 characters during user typing

Tags: wpf, string, richtextbox, system.reactive

I need get last three character from richTextBox during when the user writes some text in richTextbox.

I bind property on Text property of richTextBox from Extended WPF toolkit.

```
public string RtbText
{
    get { return _rtbText; }
    set
    {
        _rtbText = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("RtbText");
    }
}
```

I use Reactive Extensions for .NET (Rx) and make Observer on property RtbText

```
    Observable.FromEvent<PropertyChangedEventArgs>(this, "PropertyChanged")
        .Where(e => e.EventArgs.PropertyName == "RtbText")
        .Select(_ => this.RtbText)
        .Where(text => text.Length > 1)
        .Do(AddSmiles)
        .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        .Subscribe(GetLastThreeChars);

   private void GetLastThreeChars(string text)
   {
       if (text.Length > 3)
       {
           string lastThreeChars = text.Substring(text.Length - 2, text.Length);
       }
   }
```

But if I start typing in richTextBox I get this exception:

> Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
>   Parameter name: length
>
> at System.String.InternalSubStringWithChecks(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length, Boolean fAlwaysCopy)
>      at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
>      at WpfApplication1.MainWindow.GetLastThreeChars(String text) in C:\Users\Jan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\C#\Pokec_Messenger\ver.beta\IoC.Get\Pokec_Messenger\ver.beta\Pokec_*Messenger\WpfApplication1\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 97
>
>      at System.Linq.Observable.<>c*_DisplayClass389`1.<>c_*DisplayClass38b.b*_388(TSource x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another form. Which gets all the characters from some start position up to the end

```
string lastThreeChars = text.Substring(text.Length - 3);
```

maybe text.Length - 2. Untested

Answer (score 2):

If `text.Length > 3` (say it's 4) then:

```
text.Length - 2 = 2
```

So you're code is:

```
string lastThreeChars = text.Substring(2, 4);
```

This will fail as you are asking for **four** characters in the substring, which puts it out of range.

[String.Substring Method (Int32, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx)

> Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a specified character position and has a specified **length**.

Additionally your test and starting position are incorrect. Don't forget that C# arrays and strings are zero indexed. Checking for the case of length strictly greater than 3 you'll miss the case when the user has entered exactly three characters when you want to return the entire string.

Your code needs to be:

```
if (text.Length > 2)
{
    string lastThreeChars = text.Substring(text.Length - 3, 3);
}
```

If fact you don't need to specify the length:

```
if (text.Length > 2)
{
    string lastThreeChars = text.Substring(text.Length - 3);
}
```

will return the last three characters in the string.